# Using left- and right-handed mouse at the same time

Tags: windows-7, mouse, health, ergonomics

Using a right handed mouse only, I get pain in my shoulder after working with it for some hours. I used to plug the mouse from right to left; meanwhile I have two mice connected to my PC.

Unfortunately this leaves me with going to the control panel of Windows for switching the mouse buttons. I also need to adjust the sensitivity, because for some reason the sensitivity is not the same. I guess this is due to the mice being from different vendors or having different resolution (DPI).

As you can imagine I'd like to

- configure different settings for each mouse at the same time

or, if that's not possible

- switch between mice more easily, ideally with a single click

The tool needs to

- run on Windows 7 SP1 (or higher if possible), x64
- cost less than 20 USD, gratis preferred of course
- work with standard USB mouse, Microsoft drivers, no vendor specific software installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Eithermouse](http://www.eithermouse.com/)

- stores different settings per mouse

  - swap mouse buttons
  - adjust sensitivity
  - adjust double click speed
  - adjust scroll wheel
- automatically detects the active setting on mouse movement
- runs on Windows 7 or higher
- is free

Screenshot, taken from website:

[image: Eithermouse settings]